# How to define list of enumerated values in Web2Py

Tags: python, web2py

I develop a website with Web2Py framework.

It provides a way to define enumerated values as given below.

I need to define a table as given below.

```
Field('state','string', length=10, requires=IS_IN_SET(('open','closed','not_open')))
```

Also, I can define a field which can list values as given below.

```
Field('emails','list:string')
```

But, what is the syntax to combine this?
I need to define the weekend days for an organization and this should be more than 1.

I tried the following.

```
db.define_table('organization',
    Field('name','string', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('description','text'),
    Field('weekends','list:string', length=10, requires=IS_IN_SET(('sunday','monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday'))),
    redefine=migrate_flag
)
```

But it only defines an enumeration with a single value.
I verify this in the new record creation in the Web2Py appadmin interface by creating a new database record there. I can enter only one value for the `weekends` field.

Can this be done in the 'web2py' way? Or will I have to resort to creating a new weekend table in the database and make a foreign key to the organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "multiple" argument to allow/require multiple selections:

```
IS_IN_SET(('sunday','monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday'),
          multiple=True)
```

Or if you want to require exactly two choices:

```
IS_IN_SET(('sunday','monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday'),
          multiple=(2, 2))
```

If `multiple` is `True`, it will allow zero or more choices. `multiple` can also be a tuple specifying the minimum and maximum number of choices allowed.

The `IS_IN_DB` validator also takes the `multiple` argument.